# Dragging a second window along with main window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to drag a second window through the main window, whenever I move the first window the second window gets dragged along with the main window to the right of the main window.

Whatever I have tried has not worked, I've tried DragMove() but it did not move the second window it only moved the main window, I am not really experienced with C# and WPF.

Comment: What position do you want the second window to be in relation to the first window?

Comment: _"Whatever I have tried has not worked"_ -- what did you try? in what _way_ did it "not work"? What did the code do? How was that different from what you wanted? What _specifically_ do you need help with? Please edit your post to include a [mcve] and details explaining the answers to those questons.

Comment: @meysamasadi to the right side of the main window like this https://imgur.com/tsQbNi0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code. Only the difference between the last point of the first window and its current position is calculated and the value obtained is added to the position of the second window, and of course all this works in the event `LocationChanged`.

MyWindow1.cs

```
public partial class MyWindow1 : Window
{
     MyWindow2 wnd;
     Point last = new Point();
     public MyWindow1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         last.X = this.Left;
         last.Y = this.Top;
     }

        
     private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (wnd != null)
         {
             wnd.Left = (this.Left - last.X) + wnd.Left;
             wnd.Top = (this.Top - last.Y) + wnd.Top;

             last.X = this.Left;
             last.Y = this.Top;
         }
     }

     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         wnd = new MyWindow2();
         wnd.Show();
     }
}
```

MyWindow1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MyWindow1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MyWindow1" Height="450" Width="800" LocationChanged="Window_LocationChanged">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Get Window 2" Width="150" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```